# SQL Server error "Implicit conversion of because the collation of the value is unresolved due to a collation conflict."

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am getting this error while developing a stored procedure

> Implicit conversion of varchar value to varchar cannot be performed because the collation of the value is unresolved due to a collation conflict.

statement is like this

```
Select City COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS Place, State, Country FROM DEPT1
UNION ALL
Select '' AS Place, 'Arizona' As State, Country FROM DEPT2
```

but If If do this it also give same error

```
 Select City COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS Place, State, Country FROM DEPT1
 UNION ALL
 Select '' COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS Place, 'Arizona' As State, Country FROM DEPT2
```

Actually this code is written by some one else and am just editing the code, do not know why he added  COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT but If I remove it also gives the same error

> Implicit conversion of varchar value to varchar cannot be performed because the collation of the value is unresolved due to a collation conflict.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You'd need COLLATE in both places most likely.

```
Select City COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS Place, State, Country FROM DEPT1
UNION ALL
Select '' COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS Place, 'Arizona' As State, Country FROM DEPT2
```

Edit: You may need it on every string if you get it in one places

```
Select
    City COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS Place,
    State COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS State,
    Country COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS Country
FROM DEPT1
UNION ALL
Select
    '' COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT,
    'Arizona' COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT ,
    Country COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
FROM DEPT2
```

Edit2:

It happens because your column collation is probably different to your database collation. So "City" has one collation but string constants have another.

Comment: How can I remove this  COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT at all from my statement ... why is it enforcing to use this ... Actually there are 45 columns in one statement and about union ALL of 6 statements and more then half are string ...

Comment: This was a good tip for me, when I was dealing with selecting-from a couple SYS tables (or views) to find out what permission-grants all my server-logins (principals) were given.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE DEPT1 and DEPT2 so that resulting definitions of tables do not contain any COLLATE