# Implicit conversion of varchar value to varchar - collation conflict

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting the following error whilst running this script. I've tried using the following:
COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS. Please can it be sorted? Thanks

> Msg 457, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   Implicit conversion of varchar value to varchar cannot be performed because the collation of the value is unresolved due to a collation conflict

```
DECLARE @AccountID INT 
SET @AccountID = 12

SELECT TOP 1    ac.AccountID,
            co.Email,
            ao.AccountOptionID
FROM CRM.acc.Account ac
INNER JOIN CRM.[profile].[Profile] pr
    ON pr.ProfileID = ac.ProfileFK
INNER JOIN CRM.[profile].Contact co
    ON pr.ProfileID = co.ProfileFK
LEFT JOIN CRM.acc.[AccountOption] ao
    ON ao.AccountFK = ac.AccountID
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT OptionID
            FROM CRM.acc.[Option]
            WHERE [Name] = 'SMS messages') op
    ON op.OptionID = ao.OptionFK
WHERE ac.AccountID = @AccountID

UNION ALL

SELECT      u.UnsubscribeID,
        u.EmailAddress,
        u.SentEmailFK
FROM  Email.dbo.Unsubscribe u
  INNER JOIN  (
                    SELECT      CASE
                                      WHEN AccountTypeFK = 2 THEN OnlineBillingEmail
                                      ELSE EmailBillingEmail
                                END [EmailAddress]
                    FROM  CRM.acc.Account
                    WHERE AccountID = @AccountID                    
                    ) ace
        ON ace.EmailAddress COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT  = u.EmailAddress COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
WHERE ISNULL(ace.EmailAddress, '') != ''
```

Comment: whats ur DB default collation?

Comment: for DB 'Email' = Latin1_General_CI_AS and for DB 'CRM' = Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: Yeah it gives same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that you have different collation types on your database. Then you can have issues when joining tables or to tables in other databases, as in this case. To get around this you can specify the collation of columns or force a collation using the COLLATE clause when joining two columns. Check [more info about collation in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187582%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Also you need to specify the COLLATE clause where you are using the problematic column(s). [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861782/sql-server-error-implicit-conversion-of-because-the-collation-of-the-value-is-u), it answer a very similar question

It is better to stick to a single collation globally. Otherwise you will have problems.

See a detailed explanation of the [different collation styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143515%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Edited: to check column collation use this snippet

```
SELECT name, collation_name
  FROM sys.columns
  WHERE OBJECT_ID IN (SELECT OBJECT_ID
                        FROM sys.objects
                       WHERE type = 'U'
                         AND name = 'your_table_name'
                      )
    AND name = 'your_column_name'
```

Edited: added snippet to get all columns with different collation on a database

```
SELECT [TABLE_NAME] = OBJECT_NAME([id]),
       [COLUMN_NAME] = [name],
       [COLLATION_NAME] = collation
  FROM syscolumns
 WHERE collation <> 'your_database_collation_type'
   AND collation IS NOT NULL
   AND OBJECTPROPERTY([id], N'IsUserTable')=1
```

Comment: I've been using this statement to find the collation for each datbase: SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('CRM', 'Collation') SQLCollation; and I've tried forcing each column by using COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT or COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, i.e.           SELECT      u.UnsubscribeID COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,
   u.EmailAddress COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,
   u.SentEmailFK COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS but it still gives me error. but your answer was very helpful. thanks a lot, its a shame I can't click your ans as useful

Comment: That first sentece is correct `SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('CRM', 'Collation') SQLCollation`. And using it you did confirmed the collation on both databases is the same or different?  If they are equal then the problem you have is that the columns have different collation. I'm editing my answer to add a code that allows you to check your column collation and see what need to be corrected.

Comment: Yeah both dbs have same collation as Latin1_General_CI_AS. I'm just going to check each column now, thanks

Comment: Should PK and FK have the collation name? beacause on checking its giving me null for PK and FK where as for other columns its the same:Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: Then check your columns collation and see what it is different. Also try to get to the bottom of the problem, if possible, and see why the collation is different. This can cause you more troubles in the future. Once you have 15 reputation you can vote up, two more to go yet. I'm editing my answert to add another snippet to check all your columns collation at once.

Comment: You're a STAR. Its sorted now. You were absolutely right: columns had different Collation. Brilliant. Thanks for great help

Comment: if (reputation = 15) { Yaroslav = STAR } Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
ace.EmailAddress COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = u.EmailAddress COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Answer (score 0):

> Because you are doing a union all to the CRM table which has a different collation. You need to explicitly define the collation of your columns going into your union. In your case that will be UnsubscribeID,EmailAddress and SentEmailFK all should be defined with collate database_default
> Running the below should work. Let me know in the comments if this works

```
  SELECT TOP 1    ac.AccountID,
        co.Email,
        ao.AccountOptionID
 FROM CRM.acc.Account ac
 INNER JOIN CRM.[profile].[Profile] pr
 ON pr.ProfileID = ac.ProfileFK
 INNER JOIN CRM.[profile].Contact co
 ON pr.ProfileID = co.ProfileFK
 LEFT JOIN CRM.acc.[AccountOption] ao
ON ao.AccountFK = ac.AccountID
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT OptionID
        FROM CRM.acc.[Option]
        WHERE [Name] = 'SMS messages') op
ON op.OptionID = ao.OptionFK
WHERE ac.AccountID = @AccountID

UNION ALL

SELECT      u.UnsubscribeID  COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS UnsubscribeID,
    u.EmailAddress COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT  AS EmailAddress ,
    u.SentEmailFK COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT   AS SentEmailFK
FROM  Email.dbo.Unsubscribe u
INNER JOIN  (
                SELECT      CASE
                                  WHEN AccountTypeFK = 2 THEN OnlineBillingEmail
                                  ELSE EmailBillingEmail
                            END [EmailAddress]
                FROM  CRM.acc.Account
                WHERE AccountID = @AccountID                    
                ) ace
    ON ace.EmailAddress COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT  = u.EmailAddress COLLATE 
DATABASE_DEFAULT
WHERE ISNULL(ace.EmailAddress, '') != ''
```